# Deleting rows from a ListBox range multiselection VBA, deletes only the last row

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I really looked up to find a answer before asking here, but I couldn't find a solution.

I'm new at VBA, I did my best but I couldn't figure it out, I've tried arrays, with and so on, and I couldn't, so if the answer for my question has been already answered in another post, pardon me, ok? I couldn't find, probably the heading of the question is not so clear as I've looked for...

So, I am trying to delete certain rows after an user had selected them from a listbox, but the code only deletes the last row in that range selected.

Please, help me out. Thank you all.

My code is:

```
Private Sub cmdBDGDeleteExpense_Click()

Dim UserAnswer As Long
Dim i As Long

UserAnswer = MsgBox("Are you sure you would like to delete this expense?", vbCritical + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Delete Expense")

If UserAnswer = 6 Then
    For i = lbxBDGExpensesHistory.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If lbxBDGExpensesHistory.Selected(i) Then
            Worksheets("expenses_history").Cells(lbxBDGExpensesHistory.ListCount - (lbxBDGExpensesHistory.ListCount - i) + 2, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing was deleted!"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried by copy pasting the code and worked perfectly. It is a clean piece of code.  However Cells(lbxBDGExpensesHistory.ListCount - (lbxBDGExpensesHistory.ListCount - i)+2 is effectively cancelling lbxBDGExpensesHistory.ListCount and using only i+2 as row. May please try a trial run by replacing ‘.EntireRow.Delete’ with something like ‘.Font.Bold = True’ to witness the effect

Comment: NB. However my listbox is not dynamically linked. I populated it at init

Comment: Hi Ahmed AU. 

I did replace the "EntireRow.Delete" with "Font.Bold = True" and it changed all the selected rows, but not the entire row, only the row from column 1. So, meaning that the code works with multiple selection.

Said that, why does it not delete, likewise it changes the font property??? 

Could be that a problem caused by the fact that the listbox is dynamically updated?

Thanks.

Comment: After ist Deletion from bottom of the list, dynamically linked ListBox control may be getting repopulated, thus deselecting other selections. May please use Listbox.List property at init event of userform and also again after completion of deletion loop to repopulate the Listbox.

Comment: Another way to solve the problem with dynamic link, is to disable calculation before deletion loop "Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual"  and again enable calculation after deletion loop  "Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic". But Caution Error within the deletion loop may cause to keep excel calculation manual

Comment: Good morning Ahmed AU. OMG you are a genius. It was exactly what was happening, the automatic calculation was deselecting the remaining selection after the first exclusion. Adding the codes at the beginning and at the end on the "If statement when it is true" solved the problem. Thank you very much for your patience and your willingness to help me out. Cheers.